# Axiom resolution

Tags: algorithm, prolog, axiom, successor-arithmetics

I try to understand how axiom resolution works in prolog.

Let's assume that I define the two basic operations on the natural numbers:

- s(term) (stands for successor) and
- add(term, anotherTerm).

The semantic of add is given by

- add (0, x1) -> x1
- add (x1, 0) -> x1
- add(s(x1), y1) -> s(add(x1, y1))

Then, I would like to solve the equation

add (x, add(y, z)) = s(0)

I imagine that one strategy could be to

- test if the right hand side (RHS) of the equation is equal to its left hand side (LHS)
- if not see if a solution can be find by looking for the most general unifier
- if not then try to find an axiom which can be used in this equation. A strategy for doing this job could be to (for each axiom): try to solve the RHS of the equation equals to the RHS of the axiom. If there is a solution then try to solve the LHS of the equation equals to the LHS of the axiom. If it succeeds, then we have found the right axiom.
- eventually, if there is no solution and the LHS and RHS of the equation are the same operation (i.e. same signature but not same operands), apply the algorithm on each operand and a solution is found if a solution is found for each operand.

I think that this (simple) algorithm may work.
However, I would like to know if anyone has experience solving this kind of problem?
Does anyone know where I can find some documentation about a better algorithm?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks again like Erlang, whats wrong with the Prolog teachers nowadays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [*narrowing*](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~antoy/research/narrowing/FAQ.html). It is implemented in some functional-logic languages such as [Curry](http://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/currywiki/), but not in Prolog itself.

Answer (score 4):

A Prolog program is a collection of predicates.

A predicate is a collection of clauses.

A clause has the form

```
Head :- Body.
```

meaning "`Head` is true if `Body` is true".

There is a shorthand clause form

```
Head.
```

which means the same as

```
Head :- true.
```

where `true` is a builtin that is always true.

Going back to the `Body` part of a clause, `Body` is a goal which can take one of the following forms (`A`, `B`, and `C` denote arbitrary goals):

```
Atom            % This is true if Atom is true (see below).
A, B            % This is true if A is true and B is true.
(A ; B)         % This is true if A is true or B is true.
\+ A            % This is true if A is not true.
(A -> B ; C)    % If A is true then B must be true, else C must be true.
```

There are some special rules in Prolog concerning evaluation order (left to right) and "cuts" (which prune the search tree), but that's fine detail which is beyond the scope of this brief tutorial.

Now, to decide whether an `Atom` is true, `Atom` can be one of the following forms (`X` and `Y` denote arbitrary terms):

```
true                % or some other builtin with given truth rules.
X = Y               % True if X and Y are successfully unified.
p(X, Y, ...)        % True if p(X, Y, ...) matches the head of some clause
                    % and the Body is true.
```

A term is, essentially, any piece of syntax.

The key thing to spot here is that Prolog has no functions!  Where in a functional language you might define a function `add(X, Y)` which evaluates to the sum of `X` and `Y`, in Prolog you define a predicate whose head is `add(X, Y, Z)` which, if it succeeds, unifies `Z` with the term denoting the sum of `X` and `Y`.

Given all that, we can define your rules in Prolog as follows:

```
add(0, Y, Y).                        % 0 + Y = Y.
add(Y, 0, Y).                        % Y + 0 = Y.
add(s(X), Y, s(Z)) :- add(X, Y, Z).  % s(X) + Y = s(X + Y).
```

where I'm using `0` to denote zero (!) and `s(X)` to denote the successor of `X`.

Consider evaluating `add(s(s(0)), s(0), Z)`:

```
add(s(s(0)), s(0), Z)                 % Only the third head for add matches, so...
---> Z = s(Z0), add(s(0), s(0), Z0).

add(s(0), s(0), Z0)                   % Only the third head for add matches, so...
---> Z0 = s(Z1), add(0, s(0), Z1).

add(0, s(0), Z1)                      % Only the first head for add matches, so...
---> Z1 = s(0).
```

Putting all those unifications for `Z` together, we have `Z = s(s(s(0)))`.

Now, you may ask "what happens if more than one head matches in a clause" or "what happens if an evaluation path fails?", to which the answers are "nondeterminism", "backtracking", and, in general, read a Prolog textbook!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Annnnnd, having carefully reread your question, the way you'd need to express "what is/are the solution/s to add(X, add(Y, Z)) = s(0)" is `add(Y, Z, W), add(X, W, s(0))` which will terminate and give you `X = 0, Y = 0, Z = W = s(0)`, however, on backtracking, it will eventually end up in a nonterminating loop (that's Prolog for you!).

Comment: Once again we have to explain that Prolog does not solve axioms, but unifies terms, which is a weaker (but faster and more predictable) form of resolution.  Some applications actually deal with solving axioms, like Coq, Nuprl and Agda.

Comment: I'd go further and say that Prolog's claims to be a logic language are bordering on false.  Mercury is a properly declarative logic language - of course, the price Mercury pays for that is that Mercury programs run tens of times faster :-)  [Disclaimer: I was a Mercury developer for a looooong time.]

Answer (score 0):

"Knowledge representation and reasoning" by Brachmann and Levesque gives a fairly good introduction to how these things work.